# Join SHOW TABLES with table in database

Tags: mysql, database

I want put all tables name from my database to tmp_table. If table name doesn't exist  in tmp_table. SHOW TABLES give me all tables name from my db

```
SHOW TABLES:
table1
table2
table3
```

And my tmp_table in database has one row:

```
tmp_table:
table2
```

I want to my tmp_table contain:

```
tmp_table:
table1
table2
table3
```

How to select tables name from SHOW TABLES and INSERT into tmp_table.

```
SELECT tmp_table.table_name
FROM database.tmp_table
LEFT JOIN SHOW TABLES
ON  tmp_table.table_name = SHOW TABLES
```

I tried this way but it didn't work,maybe is any other way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> try this for MY SQL

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='dbName'
```